# Sapi Dynamic Grammar loading

Tags: c++, sapi

I have a sapi grammar as

```
<rule id="root">
    <item repeat="0-">
       <ruleref uri="#digit"></ruleref>
     </item>
 </rule>

<rule id="digit">
<one-of>
      <item>1</item>
      <item>2</item>
      <item>3</item>
      <item>4</item>
      <item>5</item>
      <item>6</item>
      <item>7</item>
      <item>8</item>
      <item>9</item>
      <item>0</item>
  </one-of>
 </rule>
```

I want equivalent of dynamic loading of grammar can anyone helpme on this?

I have tried

```
SPSTATEHANDLE hRule;
hr = cpGrammar->GetRule(L"digit", NULL, SPRAF_TopLevel | SPRAF_Active, TRUE,&hRule);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"1", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"2", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"3", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"4", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"5", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"6", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"7", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"8", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"9", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->AddWordTransition(hRule, NULL, L"0", NULL, SPWT_LEXICAL, 1, NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->Commit(NULL);
hr = cpGrammar->SetGrammarState(SPGS_ENABLED);
```

It doesnt work for me , am I doing the right thing?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Off the top of my head, this code looks reasonable.  You might need to call [ClearRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717874(v=vs.85).aspx) if you're doing this more than once.

Comment: Hi Eric am doing it only once. When I say it doesn't work it means I do not get the same recognized text when I load it from file and load it dynamically.So am not sure whether am doing it in a proper way.In My grammar(static) I have a element  <one-of> ,So i wasnt sure how to implement it dynamically

Comment: Stared at it some more; are you sure that you need the `SPRAF_TopLevel | SPRAF_Active` flags?  You shouldn't need them for rules that are embedded in other rules.

Comment: I feel its needed , because before giving stream for recognizer I  have to access the rule by hr = cpGrammar->SetRuleState(L"digit", NULL, SPRS_ACTIVE);.If I dont set the flags (SPRAF_TopLevel | SPRAF_Active) I wont be able to set the rule.

Comment: If this were the *only* rule in the grammar, then you would need [SPRAF_TopLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431838(v=vs.85).aspx).  But I suspect it's not.  Which also implies that the root grammar needs to be [loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413299(v=vs.85).aspx) with [SPLO_DYNAMIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431853(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Reviewed some code that built dynamic grammars, and I'm pretty sure you need `SPRAF_Dynamic` along with `SPRAF_TopLevel | SPRAF_Active`.  (At least, the code I wrote used that.)

Comment: Eric I was working on it for last few days still I wasn't able to get the solution.Yeah U are right I may have to add the field SPRAF_Dynamic.Now am able to get the working static grammar which i have posted in my grammar(edited).Am not able to implement itdynamically:(